# AWS Redshift - Are Manual Snapshots Incremental?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

As the question says, when you create Manual Snapshots for Redshift are they incremental (as the automated are?) and if so can a cluster be restored from any snapshot even if the original full snapshot is deleted? I know it can from the automated backups which are on a rolling 30 days

We are looking at a 3 or 4 node ds2.8xlarge cluster (16TB HDD) giving a total of 64TB. Given say half of that is usable, allowing for cluster replication, that is still c30TB we have to back up , with a requirement to optionally restore to a separate cluster from a point in time. Im hoping to avoid having to store monthly 30TB snapshots, even if that is in Glacier ...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just like your other question about EBS snapshots, if you have a snapshot available you can restore it. They are incremental, but Amazon handles all that behind the scenes and you don't need to worry about it. You should only think of them being incremental in the sense that you aren't charged extra for multiple snapshots of the same data. You don't have to worry about the deletion of a snapshot causing another snapshot to be unusable.

Also, again, Amazon advertises that they store these snapshots in S3 to give you an idea of the reliability of the storage. You don't get access to the S3 bucket and you can't move the snapshots to Glacier or use S3 lifecycle rules.

This is true for all AWS snapshot types, including EBS, RDS and Redshift.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I wasn't sure if that applied to manual snapshots in the context of Redshift - but I assume it does and they are all stored in this internal S3 bucket